# Three button width on screen Android

Tags: android

How can i set three buttons next to each other to fit screen size of screen in android.
For 50% 50% of screen this is used. but if i want to add a third button how can i achieve this. i.e. 35% 35% 35% and 5% for space.

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:weightSum="1.0">
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/textbox3"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight=".5"
  android:layout_width="0dip"
  android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do you exactly want? 35% 35% 35% and 5% equals 110%
Do you need 3 buttons and buffer space at right side of third button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 points to be remember to do that

1. all 3 buttons should have same(eg: 1) values in layout_weight and
2. shoudl have same layout_height and layout_width

as shown in below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`enter code here`
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```